# Canon MP600 USB-connected Scanner is not recognized by sane-find-scanner

Tags: 12.04, usb, canon, scanner, pixma

I have a Canon Pixma MP600, which is supported by xsane with pixma backend.

I have Xubuntu 12.04, this is the result of `sudo sane-find-scanner -v` command:
searching for USB scanners:

```
checking /dev/usb/scanner... failed to open (Invalid argument)

checking /dev/usb/scanner0... failed to open (Invalid argument)
```

and so on.

```
checking /dev/usbscanner... failed to open (Invalid argument)

checking /dev/usbscanner0... failed to open (Invalid argument)
```

and so on.

```
No USB scanners found.
```

It works on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.

How to fix this?